# Cell borders take cell background color when cell opacity below 1, Chrome works fine

Tags: html, css, html-table

I was making this table to look like cells have no borders by giving the cells a border the same as the container background color and the cell with a background rgba(255,255,255,.4); . I used **Bootstrap 3** but did not add bootstrap table specific classes to my markup.

As I "disable" certain cells changing their opacity to ***0.5*** I realized that the borders take the background color instead of retaining their solid blue color. Its like the borders turned from *2px solid #38cee9* to *2px solid transparent.* This happens on IE and Firefox. Chrome works just fine! WHY?

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="layout-section ng-scope">
<div class="layout-control-container">
    <table class="layout-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in section.rows" class="ng-scope">
                <td ng-repeat="cell in row.cells" width="50%" colspan="1"></td>
                <td ng-repeat="cell in row.cells" width="50%" colspan="1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in section.rows" class="ng-scope">
                <td ng-repeat="cell in row.cells" width="50%" colspan="1" class="opac5"></td>
                <td ng-repeat="cell in row.cells" width="50%" colspan="1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in section.rows" class="ng-scope">
                <td ng-repeat="cell in row.cells" width="50%" colspan="1" class="opac5"></td>
                <td ng-repeat="cell in row.cells" width="50%" colspan="1" class="opac5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in section.rows" class="ng-scope">
                <td ng-repeat="cell in row.cells" width="50%" colspan="1"></td>
                <td ng-repeat="cell in row.cells" width="50%" colspan="1"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here are the styles :

```
.layout-section 
{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(56, 206, 233);
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
table.layout-table 
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
table.layout-table tr td 
{
    padding: 10px;
    height: 85px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 5px solid rgb(56, 206, 233);
    background-color: rgb(139, 226, 242);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.opac5 
{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

I added a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alin_bumbi/PZ58s/)** to see and test it in different browsers. I need to make this work in all browsers, including IE9+, like it works in Chrome.

how can I keep the borders blue while reducing the opacity to 0.5 to the whole cell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the future, consider this article: http://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/

This code:

```
#yourElement {
-moz-background-clip: padding;     /* Firefox 3.6 */
-webkit-background-clip: padding;  /* Safari 4? Chrome 6? */
background-clip: padding-box;      /* Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 10, IE 9 */
}
```

should make the border stay outside the box. Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PZ58s/16/

Answer (score 0):

Try a border-collapse:separate; in your table.layout-table section, as per:

http://jsfiddle.net/PZ58s/3/

```
table.layout-table {
    border-collapse:separate; /* this one was added to your code */
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

It works in firefox (do not have IE to test it there).

Thanks,
nmirceac

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra `background-color` on your `td` and also remove the `opacity` on your `.opac5` class.

Instead just add the rgba background-color to your `.opac5` class and hammer force it by using an `!important`.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/PZ58s/5/***

*Relevant CS*S:

```
table.layout-table tr td {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 85px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 5px solid rgb(56, 206, 233);
    background-color: rgb(139, 226, 242);
    /* background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); <--- Remove this */
}
.opac5 {
    /* opacity:0.5; <--- Remove this */
    background-color: rgba(139, 226, 242,0.5) !important; /* <-- Add this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for pitching in.

1. The Solution given by abhitalks is not really applicable in my situation as I want to set opacity to 0.5 to all elements inside the `<td>`.
2. I Tried **border-collapse:separate** and it kinda works in FF as background is not filling the borders anymore, but the borders between cells are now doubled ( borders for neighbour cells are not overlapping anymore) ... but sadly it still doesn't fix the issue for IE all versions. Also nmirceac suggested to add **border-spacing** which actually worked in all browsers but by this time I was tired of tables...
3. I decided that TABLES ARE RETARDED so I took a `<div>` approach:
   I left the cells with no styling, no borders, no nothing, and added a div inside that takes all the cell space. Gave it border, margin, background, etc.

   ```
                                   </div>
                                   <div style="padding-left:50px;"> <span class="D-block">Lorem ipsum dolor omg nobody cares</span>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </td>
               <td width="50%" colspan="1">
                   <div class="control-holder">
                       <div class="layout-cellOverlay box-bb pad-2 pointer">
                           <div style="width:auto; padding-right:70px">
                               <div class="layout-control">
                                   <div class="giant-checkbox pull-left"> <i class="D-block fa fa-check text-center fa-2x color-white mrg-top1"></i>

                                   </div>
                                   <div style="padding-left:50px;"> <span class="D-block">Lorem ipsum dolor omg nobody cares</span>

                                   </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td width="50%" colspan="1" class="opac5">
                   <div class="control-holder"></div>
               </td>
               <td width="50%" colspan="1">
                   <div class="control-holder"></div>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td width="50%" colspan="1" class="opac5">
                   <div class="control-holder">
                       <div class="layout-cellOverlay box-bb pad-2 pointer">
                           <div style="width:auto; padding-right:70px">
                               <div class="layout-control">
                                   <div class="giant-checkbox pull-left"> <i class="D-block fa fa-check text-center fa-2x color-white mrg-top1"></i>

                                   </div>
                                   <div style="padding-left:50px;"> <span class="D-block">Lorem ipsum dolor omg nobody cares</span>

                                   </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </td>
               <td width="50%" colspan="1" class="opac5">
                   <div class="control-holder"></div>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td width="50%" colspan="1">
                   <div class="control-holder"></div>
               </td>
               <td width="50%" colspan="1">
                   <div class="control-holder"></div>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
   ```

and styles:

```
.control-holder {
padding: 10px;
height: 86px;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
border: 3px solid rgb(56, 206, 233);}
```

Now it works on all browsers as you can see in my [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alin_bumbi/PZ58s/15/) ...and life is worth living again.